# Getting top element from Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable, time-complexity

Friends I know that Hastable can't be sorted but because of good complexity I must have to use Hashtable over dictionary. Now I am in condition where I need to get top(maximum) 3 elements from Hashtable. Please show me any simplest s well as efficient way as I am dealing with millions of rows.

.....................

Input

.....................

```
hashtable.Add("A", 1000);    
hashtable.Add("B", 500);    
hashtable.Add("C", 700);   
hashtable.Add("D", 800);    
hashtable.Add("E", 400);   
hashtable.Add("F", 300);
```

.....................

Output

.....................

```
("A", 1000), ("D", 800) and ("C",700)
```

Comment: What is your definition of "top 3 elements"? I note that in your question you correctly state that Hashtables can't be sorted, so it looks like you answered your own question.

Comment: "good complexity I must have to use Hashtable over dictionary"??? What kind of "complexity" you are talking about?

Comment: `I must have to use Hashtable over dictionary` Note that `Dictionary` also has no ordering. If you need ordering you may use `SortedList` or `SortedDictionary`

Comment: Why don't you just use an OrderedDictionary? Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

Comment: Time complexity. Don't wry about those things just please show me way to sort in Hashtable only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(entry => entry.Value).Take(3);
```

Comment: OP said `I am dealing with millions of rows`

Comment: Can I convert this to list? If yes How?

differentKeys.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(entry => entry.Value).Take(3).ToList();
NOT working

Comment: Its ok hashtable has small no of records, but those millions of rows are accessing hashtable everytime. SO it seems ok. I just need way to convert to List now.

Comment: +0, possible but slower solution. Clearly sorting to take fixed number of max elements is worse than calling `Max` fixed number of times (O(n log n) for `OrderBy` vs. O(n)  for calling `Max` 3 times)

Comment: in my opinion the idea of using hashtable is itself debatable, when OP had better options ```SortedList``` or ```SortedDictionary``` as @SriramSakthivel suggested.. @Pratik .ToList() should work

Comment: Dear when you'll process for 8 millions rows, u'll change your mind from dictionary to hashtables.